# calculate number of rows that appear in the same group using R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
|A      |B      |
|-------|-------|
|1      |MPRIP  |
|1      |RAI14  |
|1      |TPM1   |
|MPRIP  |RAI14  |
|MPRIP  |CDK1   |
|2      |APOBEC1|
|2      |KHSRP  |
|2      |SYNCRIP|
|APOBEC1|SYNCRIP|
```

Dput code:

```r
structure(list(OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_A = c("1810055G02Rik", "1810055G02Rik", 
"1810055G02Rik", "2810046L04Rik", "2810046L04Rik", "4922501C03Rik", 
"4930572J05Rik", "4930572J05Rik", "4930572J05Rik", "4930572J05Rik", 
"4930572J05Rik", "4930572J05Rik", "9830001H06Rik", "9830001H06Rik", 
"9830001H06Rik", "9830001H06Rik", "9830001H06Rik", "9830001H06Rik", 
"9830001H06Rik", "9830001H06Rik", "9830001H06Rik", "A1CF", "A1CF", 
"A1CF", "A2M", "A2M", "A2M", "A2M", "A2M", "A2M", "A2M", "A2M", 
"AAGAB", "AATF", "AATF", "AATF", "AATF", "AATF", "AATF", "AATF", 
"AATF", "AATF", "AATF", "ABCA1", "ABCA1", "ABCA1", "ABCA1", "ABCA1", 
"ABCA1", "ABCA1", "ABCA1", "ABCA1", "ABCA1", "ABCA1", "ABCA1", 
"ABCA1", "ABCA1", "ABCA1", "ABCA13", "ABCA13", "ABCA2", "ABCA4", 
"ABCB1", "ABCB1", "ABCB1", "ABCB7", "ABCC2", "ABCC2", "ABCC2", 
"ABCC8", "ABCC8", "ABCD1", "ABCD3", "ABCD3", "ABCD4", "ABCD4", 
"ABCE1", "ABCE1", "ABCF3", "ABCF3", "ABCF3", "ABCF3", "ABCG1", 
"ABCG5", "ABHD16A", "ABHD16A", "ABHD16A", "ABHD16A", "ABHD16A", 
"ABHD16A", "ABHD16A", "ABHD16A", "ABHD16A", "ABHD16A", "ABI1", 
"ABI1", "ABI1", "ABI1", "ABI2", "ABI2"), OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_B = c("MPRIP", 
"RAI14", "TPM1", "ARF1", "ARF3", "CPNE4", "C8orf55", "PRKDC", 
"SPRR2B", "SPRR2D", "SPRR2E", "SPRR2G", "C1QBP", "CCDC165", "DYNLL1", 
"KIAA0889", "PPP2CA", "PPP2R1A", "PPP2R5A", "PPP2R5E", "RNF41", 
"APOBEC1", "KHSRP", "SYNCRIP", "ADAMTS1", "APOE", "IL10", "IL4", 
"LCAT", "LEP", "NGF", "PAEP", "EIF3C", "CHEK2", "MAGED1", "MAPT", 
"PAWR", "PCBD2", "RB1", "RBL1", "RBL2", "RELA", "Tsg101", "AOX1", 
"APOA1", "CDC42", "COPS5", "CREBBP", "FADD", "FLOT1", "HGS", 
"PRPF8", "SDHB", "SNTB2", "STX12", "UBC", "UGP1", "XPC", "APOA1", 
"APOA2", "CDK5RAP2", "CNGB1", "DHX9", "PIM1", "UBC", "FECH", 
"PDZD3", "Rdx", "SLC9A3R1", "KCNJ11", "RAPGEF4", "ABCD2", "ABCD1", 
"PEX19", "PEA15", "XRCC6", "RNASEL", "UBASH3A", "ACIN1", "DNALI1", 
"LAMTOR1", "TOE1", "UBC", "ABCG8", "ATP5G3", "DNAJC1", "GPRC5C", 
"HM13", "IFITM1", "RNF5", "SAFB", "SPAG7", "TMEM147", "TMEM222", 
"ABL1", "ENAH", "EPS8", "NCK1", "ABL1", "CCDC53")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can imagine A is a node and it is connected to B. In this case, 1 is connected to three different genes (as shown in B) and among these genes, MPRIP is also connected to RAI14 (as shown in row #4). I want to calculate the number of links among column B that connected to the same group (column A) . For example, in this is table, since there are three of them in group 1 and MPRIP matches RAI14 (both in the same group), then the number would be 1. Below is my expected output.

```
|A      |number of links among neighbors|
|-------|-------------------------------|
|1      |1                              |
|MPRIP  |0                              |
|2      |1                              |
|APOBEC1|0                              |
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not completely clear on the logic, could you provide a larger example.  Could items in column B have multiple matches in A? How would you count both MRIP & RAI14 in group 1 matching members in column A?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my df :) Hope it can clarify my question.

Comment: It is still unclear? why B[1] and A[4] are same? just coiincidence? or first element of a group has to be next group itself?  What'd be expected output if your data consists of those rows where A is either `1` or `2` only?

Comment: As Gene 1 is connected to three different genes, MPRIP is also connected to RAI14 (its neighbor). You can imagine A and B are nodes, and they can connect with other nodes that connected to the same nodes as them. I want to calculate the number of links between neighbors (B) which connected to A. Did I make it clearer?

Comment: This is tricky. You'll make life easier for your answerers if you provide a reprex with `dput`, so we can cut and paste your data on to our computers

Comment: updated my question with dput data. not sure if it is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Gotta get the data structures right:

```r
library(dplyr)


links <- inner_join(mydata, mydata, by = c("B" = "A"))
# now B and B.y represent your links

# join back up to the original data:
links <- inner_join(links, mydata, by = c("B.y" = "B"))

# make sure both links are in the same "A" group
links <- filter(links, A.x == A.y)  

links %>% group_by(A.x) %>% summarize(link_count = n())
```

This doesn't include any zeros. You could left join the result back on to `mydata` and fill in the zeros, if you want.

Comment: NB: not guaranteed to be fast on big data! You might be able to split-apply-combine this by group, or leverage your knowledge that groups like "1" are different from groups like "MPRIP".

Comment: Yea. It takes a long time to process.

Comment: It says vector memory exhausted :( and stop running for some reasons.

Comment: Figures (you're doing a join of a huge database on itself, think how many rows that will have.) So, can you do it by group?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expanded sample.
This maybe what you are looking for. Basically grouping by the first column (column A) and then looking to see if any of the elements from column B for each group matches any of the elements in column A

```
library(dplyr)   
df<-structure(list(A = c("1", "1", "1", "MPRIP", "MPRIP", "2", "2", 
                         "2", "APOBEC1"), B = c("MPRIP", "RAI14", "TPM1", "RAI14", "CDK1", 
                                                "APOBEC1", "KHSRP", "SYNCRIP", "SYNCRIP")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                          -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarize(sum=sum(B %in% df$A))

#df %>% group_by(OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_A) %>% summarize(matches =sum(OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_B %in% df$OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_A))
```

By the way... We Are!!!

Comment: Hmm. I've tried this but it is not really what I want to calculate. I just want to calculate the links between B.